# Magento2 how to create custom module to Show related products in minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, knockoutjs, related-products

Can anybody guide me how can I add the related products ti recently added item to cart in minicart in Magento2

I know that the magento2 minicart content is loaded by the Js layout.

I have created one module override the `Customerdata` by adding `di.xml` in my module 
But it did not work.

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mypackage_Minicartrelated" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>   
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Mypackage/Minicartrelated/etc/di.xml code**

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="Mypackage_Minicartrelated" type="Mypackage\Minicartrelated\Plugin\CustomerData" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Mypackage/Minicartrelated/Plugin/CustomerDataCart.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mypackage\Minicartrelated\Plugin\CustomerData;  
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;
class Cart { 
    public method afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
    {
        // Get the previous data
        $data = $result;
        $data .="test"; 
        return $data;
    }
}
```

But it gives me error Error: `[object Object]`

> throw new Error(jqXHR);

Can anybody can give me right direction how can I show related products in Magento2 minicart.

Comment: I have show the related products in minicart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved the error and shown the related product of recent added item to cart in minicart content**

I have created updated my module to override the content.html

app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
    <plugin name="Mymodule_Minicartrelated" type="Magentoservices\Minicartrelated\Plugin\DefaultItem" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
    <plugin name="Mymodule_Minicartrelated" type="Mymodule\Minicartrelated\Plugin\Cart" disabled="false" sortOrder="1"/>  
</type>  
</config
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/etc/module.xml

```
<!--
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */
            -->
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
                <module name="Mymodule_Minicartrelated" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
                    <sequence>
                        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>   
                    </sequence>
                </module>
            </config>
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/Plugin/DefaultItem.php

```
In this file i have sent the data of related product with item data 

            <!--
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */
            -->
            <?php

            namespace Mymodule\Minicartrelated\Plugin;


            use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
            use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
            use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;
            use \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;

            class DefaultItem
            {

                protected $productRepo;
                 protected $imageHelper;
                public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper)
                {
                    $this->productRepo = $productRepository;
                    $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
                }
                public function aroundGetItemData($subject, \Closure $proceed, Item $item)
                {
                    $data = $proceed($item);

                    /** @var Product $product */
                    $product = $this->productRepo->getById($item->getProduct()->getId());
                    $relatedProducts = $product->getRelatedProducts();
                    $relateditem= array();
                    $result=[];
                    foreach($relatedProducts as $related){ 
                    $related = $this->productRepo->getById($related->getId());
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');  
                    $currentStore = $storeManager->getStore(); 
                    $priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
                    $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($related->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
                   // $imageUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $related->getImage();    
                    //$imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($related->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail'); 
                    $result['relateditemsdata'] = [ 
                        'relatedid'        => $related->getId(),
                        'related_sku'      => $related->getSku(),
                        'relatedpermalink' => $related->getProductUrl(),
                        'relatedtitle'     => $related->getName(),
                        'relatedraw_price' => $priceHelper->currency($related->getPrice(), true, false),
                        'relatedproduct_image' =>$related->getProductForThumbnail(), 
                        'related_image' =>$currentStore->getUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product'.$related->getImage() 
                    ];

                    }  

                    return array_merge($data,$result); 
                }
            }
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <!--
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */
            -->
            <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
                <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers"/>
                <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers"/>
                <body>
                    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
                    </referenceBlock> 
                    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
                        <block name="minicart">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Mymodule_Minicartrelated/minicart/content</item> 
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </referenceContainer>
                </body>
            </page>
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

```
            <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
                <body>
                    <referenceBlock name="minicart">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Mymodule_Minicartrelated/minicart/item/default</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </argument> 
                        </arguments>
                    </referenceBlock>
                </body>
            </page>
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
 var config = {
                map: {
                    '*': {
                        'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html':
                            'Mymodule_Minicartrelated/template/minicart/content.html'
                    }
                }
            };
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<!--
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */
            -->
            <li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
                <div class="product">
                    <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
                        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                            <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </a>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <span class="product-item-photo">
                        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                            <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </span>
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <div class="product-item-details">
                        <strong class="product-item-name">
                            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name"></a>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                                <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </strong>

                        <!-- ko if: options.length -->
                        <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                            <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                                <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                                <dl class="product options list">
                                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                                    <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                                    <dd class="values">
                                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option) -->
                                            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                                        <!-- /ko -->
                                        <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option) -->
                                            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                                        <!-- /ko -->
                                    </dd>
                                    <!-- /ko -->
                                </dl>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->

                        <div class="product-item-pricing">
                            <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                            <div class="details-map">
                                <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                                <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko --> 
                            <div class="details-qty qty">
                                <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                                       for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                                <input data-bind="attr: {
                                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                                       'data-item-qty': qty
                                       }, value: qty"
                                       type="number"
                                       size="4"
                                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                                       maxlength="12"/>
                                <button data-bind="attr: {
                                       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                                       title: $t('Update')
                                       }"
                                        class="update-cart-item"
                                        style="display: none">
                                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="product actions">
                            <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                            <div class="primary">
                                <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <div class="secondary">
                                <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                                   class="action delete">
                                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

> app/code/Mymodule/Minicartrelated/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

```
<!--
            /**
             * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
             * See COPYING.txt for license details.
             */
            -->
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong>
                    <span class="text"><!-- ko i18n: 'My Cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                    <span
                        class="qty empty"
                        data-bind="css: { empty: cart().summary_count == 0 },
                                   attr: { title: $t('Items in Cart') }">
                        <!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko -->
                    </span>
                </strong>
            </div>

            <div class="block-content">
                <button type="button"
                        id="btn-minicart-close"
                        class="action close"
                        data-action="close"
                        data-bind="attr: { title: $t('Close') }">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Close' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                </button>

                <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
                    <div class="items-total">
                        <span class="count"><!-- ko text: cart().summary_count --><!-- /ko --></span>
                        <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count == 1 -->
                            <!-- ko i18n: 'item' --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count > 1 -->
                            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </div>

                    <!-- ko if: cart().possible_onepage_checkout -->
                        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('subtotalContainer') -->
                            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('extraInfo') -->
                        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->

                    <!-- ko if: cart().possible_onepage_checkout -->
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Recently added item(s)' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <div data-action="scroll" class="minicart-items-wrapper">
                        <ol id="mini-cart" class="minicart-items" data-bind="foreach: { data: cart().items, as: 'item' }">
                            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) -->
                                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item, afterRender: function() {$parents[1].initSidebar()}} --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </ol>
                    </div> 

                    <div id="minicart-related" class="minicart-related">You may also be interested in:
                    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: cart().items, as: 'item' }"> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="item product product-item">
                            <div class="product">
                                <a class="product-item-photo">
                                <span class="product-image-container" style="width: 75px;">
                                    <span  class="product-image-wrapper" style="height: 88px;">
                                        <img data-bind="attr: {src: item.relateditemsdata.related_image}" class="product-image-photo"  style="width: 75px; height: 88px;">
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="product-item-details">
                                    <strong class="product-item-name">
                                        <a data-bind="attr: {href: item.relateditemsdata.relatedpermalink}, html:item.relateditemsdata.relatedtitle"></a>
                                    </strong> 
                                    <div class="product options">
                                        <div data-bind="html:item.relateditemsdata.related_sku"></div>
                                        <div class="productprice">
                                        <div data-bind="html:item.relateditemsdata.relatedraw_price"></div> 
                                        </div> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <a data-bind="attr: {href: item.relateditemsdata.relatedpermalink},html: 'View'"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    </div>      
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <div class="primary">
                            <button
                                    id="top-cart-btn-checkout"
                                    type="button"
                                    class="action primary checkout"
                                    data-bind="attr: {title: $t('Go to Checkout')}">
                                <!-- ko i18n: 'Go to Checkout' --><!-- /ko -->
                            </button>
                            <div data-bind="html: cart().extra_actions"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->

                <!-- /ko -->

                <!-- ko ifnot: cart().summary_count -->
                    <strong class="subtitle empty" data-bind="visible: closeSidebar()">
                        <!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
                    </strong>
                    <!-- ko if: cart().cart_empty_message -->
                        <p class="minicart empty text"><!-- ko text: cart().cart_empty_message --><!-- /ko --></p>

                        <div class="actions">
                            <div class="secondary">
                                <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                                    <span><!-- ko text: $t('View and edit cart') --><!-- /ko --></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!-- ko if: cart().summary_count -->
                <div class="actions">
                    <div class="secondary">
                        <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}">
                            <span><!-- ko i18n: 'View and edit cart' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div id="minicart-widgets" class="minicart-widgets">
                    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('promotion') -->
                        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('sign-in-popup') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Not working in magento 2.3.2